# Chekbox en Listview

Tags: android

Cuando selecciono los chekbox y cuando subo para ver los demás chekbox que están ocultos porque los que seleccione se les quita el chekbox?

[image: un ejemplo del listview y chekbox]

entonces cuando tengo registros y bajo para seleccionar los demás los que suben se les quita lo seleccionado como hago que no se le quite lo  seleccionado después de que se oculte al mover de arriba hacia abajo?

Comment: estas utilizando algun adaptador personalizado?  es bueno que postees el codigo para poder guiarte si estas realizando algo mal.

Comment: si es un adaptador personalizado

Comment: lo mas seguro es que este usando un list view para esto, ellos estan hecho para solo cargar la info que ves en la pantalla, lo que esta arriba o abajo es borrado por cuestion de memoria, para esto te recomiendo cambiar el list view por un RecyclerView y te ahorraras ese problema, adicional cuando intentes guardar esa info en una base de datos, solo te guardara la que aparece en pantalla, saludos te dejo [aquí](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-listview-and-recyclerview-in-Android) un link para que veas las diferencia entre los dos (esta en ingles)

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo y tomare sus consejos como parte de mi aprendizaje ya que me encanta la programación y la lógica de los codigos y algoritmos